# Css style radio button not working when checked Django

Tags: html, css, django

I have that HTML:

```
<span class="label-text"></span><ul id="id_stars">
<li><label for="id_stars_0"><input class="star-field" id="id_stars_0" name="stars" type="radio" value="1" /> 1</label></li>
<li><label for="id_stars_1"><input class="star-field" id="id_stars_1" name="stars" type="radio" value="2" /> 2</label></li>
<li><label for="id_stars_2"><input class="star-field" id="id_stars_2" name="stars" type="radio" value="3" /> 3</label></li>
<li><label for="id_stars_3"><input class="star-field" id="id_stars_3" name="stars" type="radio" value="4" /> 4</label></li>
<li><label for="id_stars_4"><input class="star-field" id="id_stars_4" name="stars" type="radio" value="5" /> 5</label></li>
</ul>
```

And I have that CSS:

```
#id_stars{
  list-style: none;
}

#id_stars label{
  font-weight: normal;
}

#id_stars input[type=radio]{
  display: none;
}

#id_stars label{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #C1C1C1;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label{
  background: #F79414;
}
```

When the radio field is cheked, the color of the label is not changing.

Any idea?

Bonus question: How could I do custom a custom radio button near the label without touching the HTML code (generated by Django forms), instead of modifying the label like now?

Comment: It's not changing the label color because the radio buttons are inside the labels. The css you are targeting is for a sibling. It will work well if you can change the HTML. I'm not sure how to help you without doing that.

Comment: Thnaks for your answer cocoa. Not even changing taking the radio buttons out of the label is working.

Comment: you also need to target `#id_stars input[type=radio]:checked + label`

Comment: Solved! Thanks cocoa =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not changing the label color because the radio buttons are inside the labels. The css you are targeting is for a sibling. So change your html like this:

```
<li>
  <input class="star-field" id="id_stars_0" name="stars" type="radio" value="1" />
  <label for="id_stars_0">1</label>
</li>
```

also add `#id_stars` to

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label{
  background: #F79414;
}
```

```css
#id_stars {
  list-style: none;
}
#id_stars label {
  font-weight: normal;
}
#id_stars input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
#id_stars label {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #C1C1C1;
}
#id_stars input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background: #F79414;
}
```

```html
<span class="label-text"></span>

<ul id="id_stars">
  <li>
    <input class="star-field" id="id_stars_0" name="stars" type="radio" value="1" />
    <label for="id_stars_0">1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="star-field" id="id_stars_1" name="stars" type="radio" value="2" />
    <label for="id_stars_1">2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="star-field" id="id_stars_2" name="stars" type="radio" value="3" />
    <label for="id_stars_2">3</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="star-field" id="id_stars_3" name="stars" type="radio" value="4" />
    <label for="id_stars_3">4</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="star-field" id="id_stars_4" name="stars" type="radio" value="5" />
    <label for="id_stars_4">5</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

As cocoa told, the main problem was that the radio buttons are inside the labels. That is because Django is rendering the default RadioSelect widget in that way.

The solution I found that works is to create a custom render for the radio select in orther to take out the radio input from the label.

That's the way:

```
class CustomRadioInputStar(RadioInput):
    def __unicode__(self):
        if 'id' in self.attrs:          
            label_for = ' for="%s"' % (self.attrs['id'])
        return mark_safe(u'%s<label%s class="rating-star"></label>' % (self.tag(), label_for))

class RadioStarCustomRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
    def __iter__(self):
        for i, choice in enumerate(self.choices):
            yield CustomRadioInputStar(self.name, self.value, self.attrs.copy(), choice, i)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        choice = self.choices[idx]
        return CustomRadioInputStar(self.name, self.value, self.attrs.copy(), choice, idx)

    def render(self):
        return mark_safe(u'%s' % u'\n'.join([u'%s' % force_unicode(w) for w in self]))
```

Then, you just need to add the custom render to the RadioSelect widget:

```
stars = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES_STARS, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=RadioStarCustomRenderer))
```

Of course, dont forget to import the respective libraries:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.forms.widgets import RadioInput
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.utils.html import conditional_escape
```